# MEAN Stack CRUD update 404 error

Tags: node.js, angularjs, express, crud

Heads up, noob coming through. Trying to build a MEAN stack todo list. So far I've gotten everything to work except for the update option. What I've done is set up the application so that it prompts the user to write in the item they want to update. So say they add the item 'ddd.' The update button would then appear beside the item, and then the user would be given a prompt, asking them to enter the new item. The problem is whenever the user does in fact enter the new item to replace the old, nothing happens, and I instead get a 404 error in the command prompt. Any help would be much appreciated. Below you'll find my controller, routes, index.html

routes/api

```
var Todo = require('./models/todo');

module.exports = function(app) {

// api ---------------------------------------------------------------------
// get all todos
app.get('/api/todos', function(req, res) {

    // use mongoose to get all todos in the database
    Todo.find(function(err, todos) {

        // if there is an error retrieving, send the error. nothing after res.send(err) will execute
        if (err)
            res.send(err)

        res.json(todos); // return all todos in JSON format
    });
});

// create todo and send back all todos after creation
app.post('/api/todos', function(req, res) {

    // create a todo, information comes from AJAX request from Angular
    Todo.create({
        text : req.body.text,
        done : false
    }, function(err, todo) {
        if (err)
            res.send(err);

        // get and return all the todos after you create another
        Todo.find(function(err, todos) {
            if (err)
                res.send(err)
            res.json(todos);
        });
    });

});

// delete a todo
app.delete('/api/todos/:todo_id', function(req, res) {
    Todo.remove({
        _id : req.params.todo_id
    }, function(err, todo) {
        if (err)
            res.send(err);

        // get and return all the todos after you create another
        Todo.find(function(err, todos) {
            if (err)
                res.send(err)
            res.json(todos);
        });
    });
});

//update to do
app.put('/api/todos/_id', function(req, res) {
        Todo.findById(req.params._id, function(err, todos){
            todo.text = req.body.text;
            console.log(todos);
            todos.save(function() {
                if (!err) {
                    res.send(todos);
                } else if (err) {
                    res.send(err);
                }
            });
        });
    });

// application -------------------------------------------------------------
app.get('*', function(req, res) {
    res.sendfile('./public/index.html'); // load the single view file (angular will handle the page changes on the front-end)
});
};
```

controller

```
var baselTodo = angular.module('baselTodo', []);

function mainController($scope, $http) {
$scope.formData = {};

// when landing on the page, get all todos and show them
$http.get('/api/todos')
    .success(function(data) {
        $scope.todos = data;
    })
    .error(function(data) {
        console.log('Error: ' + data);
    });

// when submitting the add form, send the text to the node API
$scope.createTodo = function() {
    $http.post('/api/todos', $scope.formData)
        .success(function(data) {
            $('input').val('');
            $scope.todos = data;
        })
        .error(function(data) {
            console.log('Error: ' + data);
        });
};

// delete a todo after checking it
$scope.deleteTodo = function(id) {
    $http.delete('/api/todos/' + id)
        .success(function(data) {
            $scope.todos = data;
        })
        .error(function(data) {
            console.log('Error: ' + data);
        });
};

$scope.updateTodo = function(id) {
   $scope.newItem = prompt("Please enter your new item:", "");
    $http.put('/api/todos/' + id, {formData: $scope.newItem}).success(function(data) {
            $scope.todos = data;
        });

        $http.get('/api/todos').success(function(data) {
            $scope.todos = data;
        });
};

};
```

Comment: Let me know if you'd like to look at anything else!

Comment: Way too much code ... have you looked at the browser network trace to see what's being sent ... where is it being posted?

Comment: If you mean, have I wrapped up what's being put in a console log, then yes, I have. But nothing comes up.  I just get a 404 undefined error.  Also, I'm providing the code just in case it helps, if it helps, I would strictly look at my routes/api. Or if it helps, I can remove parts of it.

Comment: Browser developer tools -- network trace.

Comment: I checked. It's being put in the same path /todos

Answer (score 1):

It looks like, in your routes api:

```
app.put('/api/todos/_id', function(req, res) {
```

You forgot the colon in the path, therefore you can't access that variable. Try:

```
app.put('/api/todos/:_id', function(req, res) {
```

Comment: The error I get in the command prompt is todo is not defined.

Comment: Okay, so I don't have any more 404 errors thanks partly to your input (thank you!). I now get straight 200s, but the updates don't show up on the app page. Not to mention I keep getting 'text' is undefined (text is defined in my routes so I don't know why it keeps saying that).

Comment: Okay, the next problem is that you're sending { formData: item }, but on the node end: First of all you're Mongo call returns variable "todos", while you're trying to update a variable called "todo". The second problem is that you're trying to update it with req.body.text, while your item is probably inside req.body.formData.text... Check these problems out.

Comment: I tried messing with the todos todo stuff and the whole thing didn't work. Neither did the req.body.formData.text edit.